# How do I implement lambda expressions in VB.NET (Error: Expression is not a method)

Tags: vb.net, lambda

The college course I am doing requires programming in VB.NET.

I am using a VDE and am trying to implement an "Entity" class that has lambda fields. The resource I have been using to try to implement this is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions

I would like to add that I am new to VB development.

```vb
Public Class Entity
    Public entityHandler As EntityHandeler
    Public mover = Sub()
                   End Sub 'position iterating lambda (SUB)
    Public collision_resolver = Sub(e As Entity)
                                End Sub 'collision behaviour lamda (ENTITY SUB)
    Public renderer = Sub()
                      End Sub 'rendering lambda (SUB)
```

...

```vb
    Private Sub tmrMainLoop_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrMainLoop.Tick
        For Each entity As Entity In mainHandler.entity_set
            entity.mover() 'Error: Expression is not a method
        Next
    End Sub
```

I am struggling to figure out what has gone wrong and how to properly implement lambda expressions.

Comment: Just incase anyone asks: yes there are typos in this code, the IDE only autocorrects some things and spelling is hard.

Comment: You can have something like `public mover as Action = New Action(Sub() ' Some action End Sub)` and e.g., `public collision_resolver as Func(Of Entity, Action) = Function(e As Entity) Sub() e.mover()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that code to compile, you must have `Option Strict Off`. You should fix that immediately. Your field is being implicitly typed as `Object` and you can't call an `Object` reference.

With `Option Strict On`, you would be forced to specify a type for that field. The obvious type is `Action`:

```vb
Public mover As Action = Sub()
                         End Sub
```

because `Action` is a delegate type, it can be invoked like a method.

You should turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and also in the IDE options, so that it is `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will test all of this in my next compuitng lesson or when my windows laptop arrives.

Comment: You can - and should - explicitly specify the type of the field even with `Option Strict Off`, but you really ought to work with `Option Strict On` all the time unless you specifically need it `Off`, which is very, VERY rare for most people. Even when you do need it `Off`, set that at the file level and use partial classes to keep the code in those files to an absolute minimum, so you have `Option Strict On` everywhere else.